# Acceleration in an Atwood's Machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

Is the acceleration magnitude of two objects in an Atwood's Machine always the same? Or does the machine need to have a massless, frictionless pulley and massless string? What would be a proof of this?

[image]

Comment: For a (short) while I thought it was from @JeffAtwood ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, whether the pulley is massless or frictionless doesn't matter. What actually matters is the type of rope that you you use.

If the rope is inextensible, then its length must remain the same and for that to happen, the 2 objects must have the same acceleration.

If the rope is flexible, its length can change, and so it is possible that the 2 objects have different accelerations.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you!